# Oracle SQL: Select ALL rows by each of their most recent ID column

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

This is probably very simple to solve but I can't seem to Google it correctly to find the answer.

I am looking to pull all rows from a table by their most recent ID without manually typing every column name. I have this kind of already working with the following query:

```
SELECT 
 STANDARD_ID,
 MAX(ID)

FROM
 HIST_ILLUM_RT

WHERE STANDARD_ID IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY 
 STANDARD_ID
```

Which pulls all the rows that I need. I'm kind of trying to get around this by using this query:

```
SELECT 
*

FROM
 HIST_ILLUM_RT

WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID)
            FROM HIST_ILLUM_RT)
```

Which fetches all the columns but only one row. E.g
[image: Part of the row fetched]

The number of rows which should be pulled will change overtime.

Is it possible to pull all the columns as well as the rows without manually typing each column name(In this case there are over 50)? Or is there no choice but to manually type it out in Oracle sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using your own query with GROUP BY?

```
SELECT *
FROM HIST_ILLUM_RT
WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT MAX(ID)
    FROM HIST_ILLUM_RT GROUP BY STANDARD_ID
)
```

Comment: Hmm.. Didn't think of doing that seems like a good idea. This one however seems to be just doing 
SELECT *FROM HIST_ILLUM_RT
But it could work maybe. I'll keep looking at it thanks !

Comment: WAIT! I was wrong. It might actually be working let me double check.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
WITH CTE AS(

       SELECT  STANDARD_ID,ID,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition BY ID ORDER BY ID DESC) RN
       FROM HIST_ILLUM_RT
       WHERE STANDARD_ID IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT STANDARD_ID,ID
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This works without the ';' but it still selects just those two columns. I'm trying to select the 50-ish columns without having to manually type them out unless it's unavoidable

Comment: If you don't want to also select the row number (via a `select *`) then you have no choice but to list out the columns.

Comment: Ah okay. So I was looking to create a View out of this but row numbers are likely to change so I'll try to be brave and write each of them out.

Comment: Also thanks JaydipJ! I hadn't heard of CTE's before and looking them up they seem quite useful!